# How to read in, process separately and then combine several CSV files?

Tags: r

So, I am processing several different CSV files at the moment, what I want to do is to create a function where I do the same processing on all of the files and then export another CSV file, and that works perfectly. Now I want to combine the exported files into one, instead of exporting individual files for each imported one. I know this should be straight forward, so the code is not reproducible. This is the code I use:

```
#Import all files in a list
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv) 


#Order of files 1-20
i = 1:length(myfiles)

#Function
fn <- function(i) {
  df = myfiles[[i]]
  
  #Delete columns
  df1 <- subset(df, select = -c(Std..Error, z.value, Pr...z..))
  
  #Add species ID column
  df1$speciesid <- i
  
  #Transform from long to wide
  df2 <- dcast(df1, speciesid ~ X, value.var = "Estimate")
  
  #Export csv files
  write.csv(df2, file = paste(datapath,paste0("coefficients", i, ".csv"), sep = "\\"))
  
  
}

#Run function 
lapply(i, fn)
```

Comment: Do the files have the same column names? If so, you could use ```rbind```.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it worked out with just adding `bind_rows()` to `lapply()` and then exporting that file/

```
#Run function 
data <- bind_rows(lapply(i, fn))
```

Answer (score 0):

Should these files contain same columns I would use

```
if (!exists(dfcombi)) {
  dfcombi <- df2  
} else {
  dfcombi <- rbind(dfcombi, df2)
}
```

inside your function with further file write (if necessary):

```
write.csv(dfcombi , 
  file = paste(datapath, paste0("coefficients_combi", ".csv"), 
  sep = "\\")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In stead of writing to csv in your function you could do something like this

```
d0 <- lapply(your_file_path_and_names, function(f) {
  d1 <- read.csv(f)
  d2 <- do_the_data_wrangling_fun(d1) # should return a data.frame
  return(d2)
}

# d0 is a list of your wrangled data frames
#  and do.call binds all the dfs in your list to a single df
d4 <- do.call(rbind, d0) 
write.csv(d4, "your_new_data.csv")
```